# Style HTML5 range input type using CSS3

Tags: css

I am trying to get this output:

[image]

But I am getting this due to my lack of CSS knowledge:

[image]

**Here is my CSS Code:**

```
input[type=range] {
    height: 39px;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    margin: 10px 0;
    width: 100%;
}

input[type=range]:focus {
    outline: none;
}

input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    cursor: pointer;
    animate: 0.2s;
    background: transparent;
    border-radius: 0px;
    border-bottom: 5px dotted #000000;
}

input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #ddd;
    height: 25px;
    width: 50px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    margin-top: -11.5px;
}

input[type=range]:focus::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
    background: transparent;
}

input[type=range]::-moz-range-track {
    width: 100%;
    height: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    animate: 0.2s;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000;
    background: #3071A9;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
}

input[type=range]::-moz-range-thumb {
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #91FF69;
    border: 2px solid #FF6991;
    height: 30px;
    width: 15px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    cursor: pointer;
}

input[type=range]::-ms-track {
    width: 100%;
    height: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    animate: 0.2s;
    background: transparent;
    border-color: transparent;
    color: transparent;
}

input[type=range]::-ms-fill-lower {
    background: #3071A9;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000;
}

input[type=range]::-ms-fill-upper {
    background: #3071A9;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000;
}

input[type=range]::-ms-thumb {
    margin-top: 1px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #91FF69;
    border: 2px solid #FF6991;
    height: 30px;
    width: 15px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    cursor: pointer;
}

input[type=range]:focus::-ms-fill-lower {
    background: #3071A9;
}

input[type=range]:focus::-ms-fill-upper {
    background: #3071A9;
}
```

Would you please help me to get this?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing max value eg:

```
<input type="range" id="volume" name="volume"
         min="0" max="1100">
```

This will make it work smoothly

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I think you didn't get my question.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).